# DocumentPicker - Restrict user to select same file again using DocumentPicker.pickMultiple

Tags: javascript, react-native, file, picker

In my application user can select documents from gallery multiple times. I am using `DocumentPicker.pickMultiple` option but there is no option to send the previously selected files to restrict the user to reselecting the previously selected file. Is there any option to achieve this.

My code is as follows:

```
import DocumentPicker from 'react-native-document-picker';

const response = await DocumentPicker.pickMultiple({
        type: finalAllowedTypes,
        size: maxFileSize
      });
```